# How to call a function that depends on a XML file previously loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am on creating a simple class with 2 methods:

- **Init**('/path/to/xmlfile')
- **test**(stuff)

The main problem is that **test method depends on the XML file loaded to work**.
So, when I do something like this:

```
f.init('/sources/model.xml');
f.test(it);
```

it fails because **test** uses a structure that is made when the XML file is loaded.

Since I am using jQuery to load XML file, with **get** method, I can do some stuff
this way:

```
f.init('/sources/model.xml',
    function() {
       if (this.test(it) ) {
            alert('OK, it works!');
        }else {
            alert('Wrong!');
       }
   });
```

and put my callback inside the **success** callback of **get** jQuery method....
BUT, is possible do something like that I put above?

I would appreciate any help.

**Note**:
I tried with a variable "loaded" inside **test** function, and a `setInterval` function to check if the XML file is loaded, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use callbacks to prevent blocking but if you really want to have the `init` function block until it receives a response, you could opt to use the $.ajax method instead of $.get

$.ajax supports an `async` option, which if set to `false` will block script execution until the server responds

Basic Usage:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/file"
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Documentation,
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you very much @lostsource, it works!, but now i'm interested in how you can do that if you have to load some images, for example... just curiosity.

Comment: not sure if you could load `<img>` synchronously. but you can use `img.onload` callback .. this question is similar to what you're asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149829/loading-images-synchronously-with-javascript